# Celery with Multiple Rate Limits

Tags: celery, django-celery

Can celery handle multiple concurrent rate limits?  I have a task that can run no more than 10 times a second and no more than 100,000 times per day, but I read the documentation as only supporting one rate limit at a time.  As a short term hack I could limit the task and impose a different limit on the worker, but worry about what would happen with multiple workers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the author's mouth: [nope](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/2186#issuecomment-52051051).

[image: bwarren2: Is it possible to have multiple rate limits in effect on a task? For example, I have a task that should not run more than 100K times in a day, and not more than 10/s. Is this possible? — ask [Owner]: That's not possible, unless you extend the implementation of TokenBucket]